# std::thread calling static member function, crashing?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to get the following member function:

```
void partitionGenerator::parallelGens(unsigned int& count, unsigned int low, unsigned int high, map<unsigned int, unsigned int> & partMap){
partMap.clear();
count = 0;
unsigned int pval;
for(unsigned int i = high ; i >= low ; i--){
    pval = geomVal(i);
    if(pval!=0){
        partMap.insert(make_pair(i, pval));
        count+=i*pval;
    }
  }
}
```

to be called by the following function:

```
map<unsigned int, unsigned int> partitionGenerator::parallelGen(unsigned int numthreads){
if(numthreads > 4 || numthreads == 0){
    cout << "Max 4 threads" ;
    exit(0);}
unsigned int* total = new unsigned int[numthreads];
map<unsigned int, unsigned int> * threadmaps = new map<unsigned int, unsigned int>[numthreads];
map<unsigned int, unsigned int> results;
do{
    genArr();
    thread* mythreads = new thread[];
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < numthreads ; i++)
        mythreads[i] = thread(parallelGens,ref(total[i]),i*target/numthreads,(i+1)*target/numthreads-1+(i+1)/numthreads,ref(threadmaps[i]));
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < numthreads ; i++)
        mythreads[i].join();        

}while(sumArr(total,numthreads) != target);
for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < numthreads ; i++)
    results.insert(threadmaps[i].begin() , threadmaps[i].end());
delete[] total;
delete[] threadmaps;
return results;
}
```

However, every time I try to run the program, only the first thread is created, and before the thread does ANYTHING else, the program crashes and I get the error R6010 - abort() has been called.

Is there something I'm doing wrong that's glaringly obvious? This has been stumping me for a while.

Comment: There is an *awful* lot of `new[]` here. `std::vector` will be upset.

Comment: Is `std::vector` necessary though? Would it speed up the program in any way? I guess I'd like to be able to run the program and answer that question myself, but I can't seem to get the program to run at all!

Comment: Been 10 years since I've done C++ but shouldn't the mythreads array be initialized with numthreads as the size?

Comment: Ah. It's always the easy stuff that slips under your nose. Now I've got to find out why else it's crashing! Threads don't seem to end. Thanks.